# images are not displaying properly on mobile view

Tags: html, image, css, mobile

My question is about images ([Photo Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUmMF.png)) in mobile are not displaying as desire one by one, and overpass the "project" section height limits and go down to "contact" section. Can some one suggest me a solution?  In [Photo One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5fyl.png) you can see how they display in deskop view.

```css
#projects {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.img-wrap {
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-img {
  border-radius: 12px;
  max-width: 270px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="work-title-1">My Recent Work</h1>
    <h2 class="work-title-2">"Here are a few recent design projects. Want to see more?"
      <a href="#">Email me.</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <img class="img-img" src="images/04.png">
          <p class="img-description">Blockchain pioneers bringing transparency, trust, and security to supply.
            <br><button class="btn"><a class="img-link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Visit Website  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <img class="img-img" src="images/04.png">
          <p class="img-description">Blockchain pioneers bringing transparency, trust, and security to supply.
            <br><button class="btn"><a class="img-link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Visit Website  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <img class="img-img" src="images/04.png">
          <p class="img-description">Blockchain pioneers bringing transparency, trust, and security to supply.
            <br><button class="btn"><a class="img-link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Visit Website  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="img-wrap">
          <img class="img-img" src="images/04.png">
          <p class="img-description">Blockchain pioneers bringing transparency, trust, and security to supply.
            <br><button class="btn"><a class="img-link" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Visit Website  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using flex to make them appear one by one I suggest you to use :

```
.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

And if you don't want them to appear one by one on pc try to use @media screen with appropriate width for each type of screen. And for pc use: *flex-direction : row*.

I hope to have helped you,

Greetings.